# Fill layout with color with exception of some child view

Tags: android

I want to show overlay on a layout, this overlay has translucent color that fills the view with some exception. These exception will be some shape with transparent color that will highlight the background view this overlay is covering.

My question is how to set this translucent color that will fill the parent view with some color with some exception area inside this parent view.

Comment: You can use android:background attribute to set a image with transparent color and shape which you can easily create in photoshop

Comment: That won't work in my case, as I want the size and position of the transparent shape to be changeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to use "canvas.clipPath()", here is example code

```
public class CircularClipView implements View {

    final Path path = new Path();

    public CircularClipView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();

        final int viewWidthHalf = 300;
        final int viewHeightHalf = 300;
        final int radius = 100;

        path.addCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        canvas.drawColor(R.color.transparen);   //#c5000000

        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```